# Codeception: Error when run Cest test

Tags: php, codeception

When I try to run Cest test I get error:

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.2.6
Powered by PHPUnit 5.6.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors. 
PHP Catchable fatal error: 
Argument 1 passed to
CartFlowDeliverPointCest::cartFlowDeliverPointCest() must be an
instance of AcceptanceTester, none given, called in
phar:///usr/local/bin/codecept/src/Codeception/Test/Loader/Cest.php on line 37
and defined in /home/michal/www/tests/acceptance/CartFlowDeliverPointCest.php on line 20
```

My Cest code:

```
use \AcceptanceTester;

class CartFlowDeliverPointCest
{

    public function cartFlowDeliverPointCest(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {

        $homePage = new \Page\HomePage($I);

        $productNanme = 'Fotoksiążka jesień';
        $homePage -> fillSearchField($productName);
        $homePage -> clickSearchBtn();
        $searchPage -> clickFirstProduct();
        $productPage ->clickMakeProductBtn();

    }
 }
```

and my Page Object code:

```
<?php
namespace Page;

class HomePage
{
    public static $URL = '/';

    public static $searchField = ['id' => 'microsearch_fraza'];
    public static $searchBtn = "//div[@id='microsearch_fraza_container']/button";

    protected $tester;

    public function __construct(\AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $this->tester = $I;
    }


    public static function fillSearchField($productName)
    {
        $I = $this->tester;
        $I->fillField(self::$searchField, $productName);
    }

    public static function clickSearchBtn()
    {
        $I = $this->tester;
        $I->click(self::$searchBtn);
    }
}
```

My Codeception version: 2.2.6

Answer (score 1):

I think that your mistake is that class name and method name are the same,
so PHP used `cartFlowDeliverPointCest` method as a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some code missing?  You seem to be calling methods on a search page and product page without first establishing them the way you have for the home page.  Shouldn't cause this specific error but will certainly be a problem once you've resolved this one.